# Pivot Tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table counting occurrences of a product on a computer. So the rows are the name of a computer. The columns are Adobe products. The last column is a COUNTA, so every machine that has a product, get a one under the product name, and totaled at the end. I want to know if it is possible filter the table by machines that have two or more counts in its row. So if a machine had a one, it would be removed. I would also like to do this vice versa. If a machine only had one mark in one comlumn, filter by that. Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by aligning my "CountA" column right next to the pivot table as shown below.  (Note that my pivot table uses the "classic" layout; I don't know if it will make a difference.) Then, when I selected cell L5 and turned on the filter in that cell, Excel "extended" the filter range to include the pivot table.  The options you wanted are now available from the dropdown appearing in L5 (see the 2nd screenshot below).

[image]

[image]